# Strongloop Model with Identity Column on the database

Tags: node.js, strongloop

Strongloop Models automatically do the validation checking for me based on the json file I setup, but I have a case that, the customerid column is an identity column on mssql, but the "required" property is set to "true" in the json file. Therefore, when I try to create a new customer, it will keep giving me a validation error, because customerid doesn't exist (which should be generated by the database). I don't want to change the "required" property to "false", I would still want to keep the validation checking for Update operation. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

ID properties
A model representing data to be persisted in a database usually has one or more ID properties that uniquely identify the model instance. For example, the user model might have user IDs.
By default, if no ID properties are defined and the idInjection property is true (or is not set, since true is the default), LoopBack automatically adds an id property to the model as follows:

```
id: {type: Number, generated: true, id: true}
```

The generated property indicates the ID will be automatically generated by the database. If true, the connector decides what type to use for the auto-generated key. For relational databases, such as Oracle or MySQL, it defaults to number. If your application generates unique IDs, set it to false.
To explicitly specify a property as ID, set the id property of the option to true. The id property value must be one of:
true: the property is an ID.
false (or any value that converts to false): the property is not an ID (default).
Positive number, such as 1 or 2: the property is the index of a composite ID.
In database terms, ID properties are primary key column(s) are. Such properties are defined with the 'id' attribute set to true or a number as the position for a composite key.